# CMake: Output a list with delimiters

Tags: cmake

By default, CMake outputs lists without delimiters, eg

```
set(my_list a b c d)
message(${my_list})
```

Outputs

```
abcd
```

How can you (easily) make CMake output something like what is actually stored?

```
a;b;c;d
```

(A typical use case is for outputting a list of search paths)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Enclose the dereferenced variable in quotes.

```
set(my_list a b c d)
message("${my_list}")
```

Outputs

```
a;b;c;d
```

Comment: Thanks. The same applies when outputting to a file. I wish the thing was better explained in the documentation...

Comment: @Antonio Just ${my_list} without quotes is a list. Passing a list to a function (like message) passes it as-if multiple arguments are passed. So the OP had the equivalent of `message(a b c d)` which catenates each elements as a string.

Comment: Sometimes CMake makes very little sense, why does it matter whether you do message on `${my_list}` or `"${my_list}"`? Makes me think they really did not think the details of the scripting language through very well at all.

Comment: I just had a thought that might explain some of this `"${}"` vs `${}` behavior, I think `message(${myList})` expands into `message(a b c d)` which cmake interprets as "message, concatenating a,b,c,d" and you get `"abcd"`. Whereas if you put it in quotes, it expands `"${mylist}"` into `"a;b;c;d"` (a string with the ;s in it) and prints out that string.

Answer (score 12):

You could write a function to join the items of a list together with a delimiter, and then print that out instead. For example, such a function:

```
function (ListToString result delim)
    list(GET ARGV 2 temp)
    math(EXPR N "${ARGC}-1")
    foreach(IDX RANGE 3 ${N})
        list(GET ARGV ${IDX} STR)
        set(temp "${temp}${delim}${STR}")
    endforeach()
    set(${result} "${temp}" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction(ListToString)
```

Then, you could use it like so:

```
set(my_list a b c d)
ListToString(str ", " ${my_list})
message(STATUS "${str}")
```

Which outputs:

```
a, b, c, d
```

Comment: Do you have the argument names backwards?

Comment: For some reasons, it doesn't work for me. The code can be greatly simplified by using extra args accessible with reserved  function `${ARGN}` variable.

Answer (score 1):

from the cmake docs:

```
list(JOIN <list> <glue> <output variable>)
```

New in version 3.12.

Returns a string joining all list's elements using the glue string. To join multiple strings, which are not part of a list, use JOIN operator from string() command.

Answer (score -1):

When you have the string with `;` between the items, you can also replace those `;` by any other delimiter using `string(REPLACE ...)`. For example:

```
set(my_list a b c d)
string(REPLACE ";"  ", " str "${my_list}")
message(STATUS ${str})
```

Comment: This solution is not good if an item may have an escaped semicolon (`\;`), but I liked the idea.